# Show only distinct values in a dropdown

Tags: php, arrays, templates

I have a form containing a drop-down.  The form links to a products table. One field in that table is 'mfg name'.  The code below returns the manufacturer for EACH product.  Whereas I seek a drop-down to show a distinct list of manufacturers.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <?php echo Form::label('mfg name', 'mfg', array('class' => 'col-md-4 control-label')); ?>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <!-- Datalist-->
    <input type="text" id="default" list="mfg" placeholder="mfg name" class="form-control input-md" name="mfg">
    <datalist id="mfg">
    <?php 
        foreach ($products as $prod){?> 
        <option value="<?php echo $prod->mfg; ?>">
    <?php   }?>
    </datalist>
  <datalist id="json-datalist"></datalist>
  </div>
</div>
```

So how can one go about showing distinct manufacturers list as a drop-down?

Comment: Do it on your controller and get a list of distinct mfg via query and pass it to your view

Comment: You just need to query manufacturers instead of products, then loop over that.

Comment: Why did this get down voted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more efficient method would be to query the distinct manufacturers into its own array and iterate over that. However, given the context you have provided and assuming you are using PHP >= 5.5, you can use the [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function combined with [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) function:

```
<?php foreach(array_unique(array_column($products, 'mfg')) as $mfg) {?>  
      <option value="<?php echo $mfg; ?>">
<?php   } ?>
```

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid array_column will work with objects. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php